# Add full text index facility to SQL Server instance

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2012, installation, full-text-search

Can anyone help me to add full text index facility to a SQL Server instance? FYI  it is cluster environment, SQL Server 2012 Developer Edition.

Running `select serverproperty('isfulltextinstalled')` returns value 0.

Comment: You should just be able to add the Full Text option, rather than just do a complete reinstall. Go to the install page, and add features.

Answer (score 1):

When you install a clustered instance, the fulltext components are installed by default and it is not possible to de-select them. If you don't have fulltext installed, you're in big trouble. Are you sure the components are not there? What does `SELECT SERVERPROPERTY('IsFulltextInstalled')` return? If it returns false, I'm afraid you will have to reinstall this instance. I had the same thing happening to me once and there was no way other than reinstalling from scratch.